# ROS failure after system crash

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I got a problem after my computer crashed. A few days ago I shut off the power of my computer by accident and caused a problem like "
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting / sys/ on root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or dirctory"
as a result I couldn't get into the ubuntu operating system. I fixed it following the guidance found on someone's blog, with the command "sudo fdisk -l".

However, there comes an other problem which is quite likely to be caused by the former accident. That is my ROS no longer works, as all ROS related commands are now invalid, including the command "roscore", because they are "not found". But I checked the file folders, the ROS folder seems intact, and I checked the bashrc, there was a line "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash", I am completely muddled....

I wonder if you could help me solve this with out reinstalling ROS, because I am afraid reinstalling ROS may erase some important files or settings. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45282/ros-failure-after-system-crash/) by [yuannian](https://answers.ros.org/users/3339/yuannian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you check the following items:

1. Is there any error when running "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash"?
2. What is the output given by "which roscore"? It should be "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscore".
3. Do a less "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscore" and see if you can open the file.

(do not do this as root)

It depends on your ROS setup but there is very high chances that removing the ROS packages, re-installing them and then rebuilding all the packages compiled from source will fix your problem without losing any data. Always make a backup first if you are unsure.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2